# reference to class property in OnMethodBoundaryAspect

Tags: c#, .net, postsharp, aop

Is it possible to reference in an aspect to properties of the class using the aspect?

following example:

```
public class Device
{
    public bool IsRunning { get; set; }
    public bool IsOffline { get; set; }

    [Offline]
    public void Start()
    {
        IsRunning = true;
    }

    [Offline]
    public void Stop()
    {
        IsRunning = false;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Offline : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        // should be something like
        if (device.IsOffline)
        {
            args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to intercept in OnEntry if the IsOffline property of the class is true.
Of course there are many devices, therefore injection of one device to the aspect doesn't seem feasible.

Also, as it is an api I do not want do pass it as an argument (someDevice.Start(someDevice.IsOffline)), where I could get the state via it's MethodExecutionArgs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'args.Instance' will give you the instance where the aspect has been applied too.

You will need to cast this to something that you'll be able to use, an Inteface being applied to all classes should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Another option available is to "import" the property from the target class to the aspect, as described on [this documentation page](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/members). You would need to implement [IInstanceScopedAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/T_PostSharp_Aspects_IInstanceScopedAspect) interface, add a new public field to hold the "imported" property and mark that field with [ImportMemberAttribute](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/T_PostSharp_Aspects_Advices_ImportMemberAttribute).

```
[Serializable]
public class Offline : OnMethodBoundaryAspect, IInstanceScopedAspect
{
    [ImportMember("IsOffline", IsRequired = true)]
    public Property<bool> IsOffline;

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        if (this.IsOffline.Get())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }


    // IInstanceScopedAspect implementation below:

    public object CreateInstance(AdviceArgs adviceArgs)
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }

    public void RuntimeInitializeInstance()
    {
    }
}
```